# How to deploy storybook to Vercel

Tags: reactjs, storybook

I am trying to storybook to Vercel, my configuration as code`"build-storybook": "build-storybook"` in my package.json. How to deploy this storybook to Vercel?

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a guide to make deploying Storybook to Vercel easier. Hopefully this helps, let me know if you have further questions.

https://vercel.com/guides/storybook-with-vercel

Comment: This deploys Storybook only, how about if deploying both the Next.js project and Storybook?

Comment: Same question as in the comment above. But also in my case it's a self managed Gitlab. So I can only do it from CI pipelines. It's not clear how to specify a build script and dist folder to Vercel build and deploy commands

Answer (score 2):

I was able to deploy Storybook on Vercel by keeping all settings default except "Build & Development Settings" where I changed the following settings:
[Build & Development Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmqIu.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).